# How to add custom HTML to node content?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I'm new to Drupal coming from Wordpress, but I was able to put a site up&running. Theming is easy in WP, but I have not figured that out in D7.

I have a Content Type and the node-content output HTML as below. But I wanted to add custom html in-between section of the node-content:

```
<div class="node-content">
    <div class="section field field-name-field-xxx ">
    ....
    </div>
    <!--need to add My Custom HTML here-->
    <div class="section field field-name-field-yyy ">
    ....
    </div>
</div>
```

I have searched online but I am not getting the basic instructions how to proceed. Presently I'm using a child theme of [Zircon](https://www.drupal.org/project/zircon).

Any help?

Comment: Highly recommend watching the theming series on drupalize.me. You will get an answer here eventually, but if you are brand new to Drupal theming, I suggest absorbing all of that information first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [custom template file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions) node--type.tpl.php where `type` is the machine name of your content type.

Place it in your theme's templates folder `/sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/templates` and clear/flush the cache to see changes.

Ex: Article content type: **node--article.tpl.php**

```
<?php print render($content['field_xxx']); ?>

// custom html goes here

<?php print render($content['field_yyy']); ?>
```

Comment: Thank You for the Idea. am too lazy to type all the code into `node--[type].tpl.php` so I research further based on the you provided and I was able to customized the field I need by creating `field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php` file. This Link should be useful for some [link]https://3cwebservices.com/drupal/how-override-field-templates-drupal-7[/link]